# How to code PHP function that displays a specific div from external file if div called by getElementById has no value?

Tags: php, function, html, if-statement

Thank you for answering my question so quickly. I did some more digging and ultimately found a solution for grabbing data from external file and specific div and posting it into another document using PHP DOMDocument. Now I'm looking to improve the code by adding an if condition that will grab data from a different div if the one called for initially by getElementById has now data. Here is the code for what I got so far.

External html as source.

```
<div id="tab1_header" class="cushycms"><h2>Meeting - 12:00pm to 3:00pm</h2></div>
```

My PHP file calling from source looks like this.

```
<?php

$source = "user_data.htm";
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTMLFile($source);
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$tab1_header = $dom->getElementById('tab1_header');

?>


<html>

<head>
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>

<div><h2><?php echo $tab1_header->nodeValue; ?></h2></div>


</body>


</html>
```

The following function will output a message if a div id can't be found but...

```
if(!tab1_header)
{
    die("Element not found");
}
```

I would like to call for a different div if the one called for initially has no data. Meaning if `<div id="tab1_header"></div>` then grab `<div id="alternate"><img src="filler.png" /></div>`. Can someone help me modify the function above to achieve this result.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this solely with PHP includes unless you put the divs into separate files. Look into PHP templating; it's probably the best solution for this. Or, since you're new to the language, try using variables:

master.php

```
$description1 = '<div id="description1">Some Text</div>';
$description2 = '<div id="description2">Some Text</div>';
```

board1.php

```
include 'master.php';

echo $description1;
```

board2.php

```
include 'master.php';

echo $description2;
```

Alternatively, you could use JavaScript, but that might get a little messy.

Comment: JavaScript would be a terrible idea for this

Comment: i agree. i just said it's an option.

Comment: i answered his specific question, then expanded my answer based on the spirit of the question. he's using html, so i felt it pertinent to mention javascript as another way to grab chunks of html and do things with them. sure, it sucks for this particular example, but the asker might not have even known about javascript, so i was hoping he might get curious and look into it. there are much better ways to do what he's trying to do in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

either split up master.php so div1\2 are in a file each or set them each to a var, them include master.php, and use the appropriate variable

master.php

```
$d1='<div id="description1">Some Text</div>';
$d2='<div id="description2">Some Text</div>';
```

description1.php

```
include 'master.php';
echo $d1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is: although it's possible it's probably **very bad** idea taking this approach.

Longer answer: the solution may turn out to be too complicated. If in your `master.php` file is only HTML markup, you could read content of that file with `file_get_contents()` function and then parse it (i.e. with [DOMDocument library functions](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtmlfile.php)). You would have to look for a div with given id.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile($file);

$divs = $doc->getElementsByTagName('div');

foreach ($divs as $div) 
{
   if( $div->getAttribute('id') == 'description1' )
   {
    echo $div->nodeValue."\n";
   }
}
?>
```

If your `master.php` file has also some dynamic content you could do following trick:

```
<?php
ob_start();
include('master.php');
$sMasterPhpContent = ob_get_clean();
// same as above - parse HTML
?>
```

Edit:

```
$tab_header = $dom->getElementById('tab1_header') ? $dom->getElementById('tab1_header') : $dom->getElementById('tab2_header');
```

Comment: terrible idea, complete overkill and the wrong approach. he said he is "I'm very new PHP" don't take his request to literally.

Comment: @Dagon, author wanted to know if it is possible - so it is possible and I agree that it's an overkill (as I stated in my answer).

Comment: I agree that this solution can be **slow** - there is difference between being _slow_ and _wrong_. Mind that sometimes only solution you can have is a slow one. 
- Is it possible to ride on one wheel? -Yes. Is it most comfortable way to ride on a bike? -Probably not. Still, it's possible.
Is it understandable now?

Comment: @wiktor the author wanted to know if it was possible using php includes. you haven't used a single include in your main answer, so you haven't even answered his question literally, let alone provided a reasonable solution.

Comment: @sgroves, you're right, there is no solution with include in my answer - I would downvote my answer if that would be possible. Thank you for your input :)

Comment: @Dagon, sgroves - I invite you to [discussion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/180239/222306) if you feel like to. I'm surprised but ready to acknowledge that I'm wrong :)

Comment: @Wiktor I ended up using DomDocument for a solution more or less like you suggested but now I'm looking to improve it with an if statement. Could you please look at my new question? Thank you for your help.

Comment: @TommyG Take a look at my edit: you can check if given element is present, if so assign to `$tab_header` `tab1_header` or `tab2_header` otherwise.